# ASP .NET AJAX UI stuff

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I had been working on server side(c#) for a couple of years. But now I have been put on the UI stuff. I know ASP.NET in detail. But the landscape in UI stuff has changed dramatically from last 2 years. Everyone talks about jquery, json, asp .net ajax extender. I don't know how to cope up with this. Any thoughts on how I could come up to speed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to get a solid foundation in Javascript/JSON first.

After that, move on to [jQuery](http://jquery.org) (a Javascript library to make your life infinitely easier).

Whatever time you have leftover, check out the [ASP.NET AJAX Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajax/) and how to develop/extend your own custom ASP.NET AJAX Controls.

Comment: I agree, but not with the ASP.NET AJAX Toolkit. I say skip that, way to bloated. The push to using jQuery, being integrated with MS, is the way to go!!!

Comment: @durilai I only mentioned the .NET AJAX stuff because the OP brough it up. Otherwise I would've said skip and and learn how to develop UIs with JS/jQuery/HTML and use .NET MVC for the backend.

Answer (score 0):

The only advice I can give you is - take up each of the items you mentioned & go through the online documentation - something like jQuery & json are pretty useful & simple to grasp even though you might not cover 100% surface area.

Answer (score 0):

Most of those new things (json,ajax,etc) come up with ASP.NET MVC.

**jQuery**:  A wonderful javascript framework for dealing with the HTML DOM.  Does great things for UI and AJAX.  Now included with, and fully supported by, Visual Studio.

**AJAX**:  Asynchronous Javascript And XHTML.  Get/post data from a webpage without doing a full postback.

**JSON**:  JavaScript Object Notation.  Just another data format, less verbose than XML.  Look into JSON.NET for more information.

Download the [NerdDinner](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/) application for a good ASP.NET MVC sample.  I'm not sure how much of the above technologies are used by NerdDinner, but it's a start.